# RegularExpressionValidator - Windows ID Validation

Tags: .net, asp.net, regex, validation

I'd like to setup a RegularExpressionValidator to ensure users are entering valid windows IDs in a textbox.

Specifically, I'd like to ensure it's any three capital letters (for our range of domains), followed by a backslash, followed by any number of letters and numbers.

Does anyone know where I can find some examples of this type of validation...or can somebody whip one up for me? :)

Language is VB.NET if it matters...

Comment: Worth mentioning is, that RegularExpressionValidator never complains about empty inputs, even if they don't match the expression. You'd need to use RequiredFieldValidator in addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
^[A-Z]{3}\\[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

You may be able to abbreviate. To embed in a string in C# (if that's your language) you need to escape the backslashes:

```
"^[A-Z]{3}\\\\[A-Za-z0-9]+$"
```

If you want to restrict to known domains then:

```
^((AAA)|(BBB)|(CCC))\\...
```

Comment: It doesn't - in fact, I've just noticed your talking about a RegularExpressionValidator, so you can ignore the C# comment.

Comment: thats what i was thinking...since it's all in the markup code it doesn't matter.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex

```
^[A-Z]{3}\\\w+$
```